# Django disable cascade delete from settings file

Tags: python, django, django-models

i just noticed that deleting an object which has a relation to itself causes to delete the related object as well:

```
class STH(models.Model):
    ...
    partner = models.ForeignKey(STH, blank=True, null=True)
```

---

```
In [1]: sth = STH.objects.get(name = 'sth01')

In [2]: sth.partner
Out[2]: <STH: sth02>

In [3]: sth.partner.partner
Out[3]: <STH: sth01>

In [4]: sth.delete()
Out[4]: (2, {'app.Disk': 0, 'app.STH': 2})
```

.

I' d like to change this behaviour ***from setting.py*** that this won' t delete the partner, only the original object and set the relation to NULL .

How can i achieve that?

Django: 1.9.x
Python: 3.4.5
Postgresql: 9.4.x

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the [**`on_delete`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) argument  as [**`DO_NOTHING`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING)

```
class STH(models.Model):
    ...
    partner = models.ForeignKey(STH, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

**UPDATE**
as [@Kevin Christopher Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395796/kevin-christopher-henry) mentioned You can set it to [**`SET_NULL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL) ***since you are defined your FK relation with `null=True`***

> Is it possible to do by using `settings.py`?

AFAIK, you can't do it, because it's a DB alteration command (internally). So, you should edit all required model and migrate to get the desired result

Comment: This should be `SET_NULL`.

Comment: This is a working answer, but as i wrote i' d like to do it from the settings.py (for all the objects in the system). Is that possible somehow?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanx for the tip :)

Comment: Too bad, but thanks. However, i remember in previous versions of Django (and maybe with different DB) it was not the case, Cascade was not there (by default).

Comment: *bad*? Did I miss something?

Comment: In the [release notes of Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0) they're mentioning about this ***`on_delete`*** argument